# IOS 7 Table cell not show

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

I am creating table view cell dynamically.
My problem is that `textLabel` of the cell is not visible.

The code was working on iOS 5 and iOS 6, but is not working on iOS 7:

```
cell.datelbl.text = [dateCalcuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
cell.datelbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: what is that code fragment...?

Comment: can you set the textcolor to be something other than white. then seen if it is still missing.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of what your are seeing in iOS5/6 and iOS7.

Comment: ios7: URL  http://s13.postimg.org/oun8akc9j/screen_shot3.png

Comment: ios6: URL  http://s22.postimg.org/tg7ps3tpd/screen_shot_9.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the text of `textLabel`, you should set its `text` property. It seems you mistakenly set the text and color of custom UITableViewCell subclass property `datelbl`, not the `textLabel`.

If however you like to set the text of the `datelbl` property, make sure that:

- the label is properly connected to an IBOutlet in Interface Builder
- Auto Layout is either not used or correctly configured
- the text color of the label is not the same as the background
- the text for the label (from your array) is not empty

Comment: you can't understand my qustion.The code was working on iOS 5 and iOS 6, but is not working on iOS 7.

Comment: You can't understand my answer. Any of these things could be broken in iOS 7 depending on how you implemented them. Judging from your code and how you stated the problem, it is likely that your implementation could lead to unexpected results. Go through the checklist above.